# Time based lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, formula, formulas

i basically have a schedule for employees. it is a simple excel table with name and start time with the current time in cell "E1"

```
Name1    09:00
Name2    10:00
Name3    11:00
Name4    12:00
Name5    13:00
Name6    14:00
Name7    15:00
Name8    16:00
Name9    17:00
Name10   18:00
```

I would like to return whose shift it is based upon the current time.

For example if the current time is 09:59 the return value should be "Name1". Not `Name2` as this is closest (the way my current formula works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
=INDEX(D1:D10,MATCH(NOW()-TODAY(),E1:E10,1))
```

NOW()-TODAY() gets the current date, MATCH find the row of the first value that is smaller or equal than the value and index returns the name in the corresponding row.

Comment: I don't understand why you have 0.5/24. If 09:59 is the time now, your formula returns Name2.

Comment: oh i misunderstood the question.